# Is data sent via HTTP POST when the Server does not exist?

Tags: http, ssl, post

I work for a large-ish advertising company. We've created a very lightweight clone of the PayPal IPN so we can offer CC Processing services for our top advertisers.

Like the PP IPN, it's a simple RESTful interface.

I deliberately instructed our admin guys to configure the vhost for this web app to only respond to requests on port 443.

This particular question is beyond my HTTP Protocol knowledge:

This may vary from browser to browser, but when a user submits a form, and the ACTION for that form is, say http://www.somesite.com, if the browser cannot resolve that site, does the post payload ever get sent over the wire?

I know this is a bit esoteric and it's more of an implementation question than something that exists in the HTTP RFC (as far as I could tell). Any takers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before sending any data the browser needs to open a TCP connection to the target site. Since this connection to the target site cannot be opened in the first place, no data can be sent.

**Update** (Thanks for the hint in the comments): 
Use HTTP-Requests like POST to avoid sending data over the wire which could be intercepted by proxies *before* the existence of the target could be checked. With proxies the TCP-connection is always established successfully and the HTTP-request-header is sent to it. The POST-request contains the additional data in his request-body which should be sent only if the request header returns no error. Nevertheless, the implementation of proxies differ and I cannot guarantee that there is no proxy which returns an error if the target-site is non-existing. But in such a case I don't know any way where you could avoid sending the complete data over the wire...

Comment: What about proxies? The client will have no problem connecting in that case.

Comment: True. But when proxying HTTP-posts the proxy would have to cache all the post-data (which can reach several MBs) before it passes it on to the non-existing target. As this would be very inefficient I doubt that it works that way. Haven't found a documentation on how it works in detail tough...

Comment: The HTTP-request is split in header and body. The header is send first, when no error returns (ie. the proxy couldn't connect the target), the body is send afterwards. POST-requests hold the data in the request-body so use these to avoid sending data over the line to non-existing servers.

Comment: Kos: It's been a while, but I wanted to thank you for your help with this. It settled an internal debate between myself and our release manager :) At the end of the day, it's our customers job to implement our API correctly, I just believe in setting people up for success.